# How to add a new record into a existing labelled node in neo4j GraphDB reading from csv file

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I am trying to add new record that is a whole row into a labelled node in  neo4j graph db. Lets say I have  node named Customer

```
╒══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"n"                                                                   │
╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│{"DISTRICT":"abc","THANA":"xyzzy","DIVISIO│
│N":"abc","REGDATE":"1-2-2015","ID":"0123"}          │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
```

I want to add  another row consists with these fields and relevant value from reading a csv file. This nodes holds a  large data. so I think apoc with periodic iteration will be  good idea for processing it parallel. but I am confused  about  adding a whole row into a labelled node. I have learnt to update property information through "merge  on set on create" approach but can't perform to add new record into labelled node. I am expecting to see a table consisted new record having labelled node (customer). kindly help me to solve this

Comment: Please include the work you have done so far and the issues you are facing.

Comment: Parallel processing with `MERGE` and apoc periodic iteration doesn't work. It throws NULL POINTER Exception. and if you set parallel processing false, then it will perform similar to `LOAD CSV`. Use periodic iteration and parallel processing only if you are using `CREATE`.

Comment: The wording of the question is confusing. I don't think you really want to add multiple "rows" into a single labelled node. I believe you want to create *multiple* nodes that have the same label (presumably `Customer`). Is that correct? If so, take a look at [LOAD CSV](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/load-csv/).

Comment: @cybersam I am wanting  to add multiple rows in single label customer . lets  say, my customer node has 10 rows with  specific columns. I want  to add more 5 rows in a way such that my updated customer node contains 15 rows. basically its a row updating in single label. any  approach will be appreciable .if there is no way then it is also appreciable :) thanks for your message

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "row"? Your table looks like it is from the neo4j browser, which includes a tabular visualization of various results is one or more rows. But that does not mean that a single node has multiple "rows". Your table looks like it is just showing a row containing one node (but since you did not provide your query, I am just guessing),

Comment: yeh you are right I am seeing it as tabular form  from neo4j browser.where multiple rows are labeled as single node. I am newbie  in neo4j so if my concept is wrong kindly correct me

Comment: oh now I have got your idea.  you are right  I am wanting to create multiple node that  have same label  :) sorry  for poor understanding . I have just checked it right now.In  that case creating node from load csv will be  ok .

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to use [LOAD CSV](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/load-csv/) to create your neo4j data from a CSV file. Please pay attention to the [Introduction](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/load-csv/#query-load-csv-introduction) section of the docs for important info on how to configure the neo4j server and for where to store the CSV file (if you want to use a local file).

Suppose your data is in a `input.csv` file that starts with a header row, like this:

```
DISTRICT,THANA,DIVISION,REGDATE,ID
abc,xyzzy,abc,1-2-2015,0123
def,foobar,nbc,1-3-2015,0124
```

This query should then create one `Customer` node per file row:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///input.csv' AS row
CREATE (c:Customer)
SET c = row
```